# c# method with null parameter

Tags: c#

Can somebody explain why C# takes method `static long Foo(params object[] args)` for second expression `Foo(null)`? `Foo(object a)` has the correct signature to be called too.

How I can find the answer myself? I tried to look through ILDASM, but it doesn't help :(.

```
class Bar {};

static short Foo<T>(params T[] args)
{
    return 4;
}

static long Foo(params object[] args)
{
    return 3;
}

static int Foo(object a, object b)
{
    return 2;
}
static byte Foo(object a)
{
    return 1;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Foo() + Foo(null) + Foo(new Bar()) + Foo(new Bar(), new Bar()));
}
```

Comment: This is not a constructor, just an ordinary method. Could you please correct your (otherwise interesting) question.

Comment: Your method doesn't do anything with the parameters, it's always returning a short regardless.